# Understanding DNA match of 1,723 cM

Tags: dna, autosomal-dna, relationship-analysis, half-siblings

I have a DNA match of 1,723 cM with a male 6 years younger than me. His father is one of a twin, could my match be not my half-sibling but my 1st cousin.

Answer (score 2):

Given the 1723 cM number, I'm interpreting "his father is one of a twin" as "his father and my father are identical twins". This means that genetically, you and your first cousin are half-siblings.

The difference between genetic relationships and biological relationships is a nuance that the consumer DNA market ignores wholesale. If my child were to take a DNA test, all of the sites would claim a parent-child relationship with my sibling, with cheerful 100% certainty. (Just to make it clear: my sibling is childless, so all of the sites would be 100% wrong about the biological relationship.)

Answer (score 0):

The [Shared cM Project 4.0 tool v4 for 1,723cM](https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4/1723) does not suggest first cousin but it does suggest half-sibling.  If grandparent, grandchild, niece/nephew and uncle/aunt are ruled out or considered unlikely based on your age difference then half sibling seems to be the most likely.  Sibling is also a remote possibility.

Comment: Note that given the mention of twins in the question, this answer needs a strong disclaimer that it's talking only about _genetic_ relationships, not biological or social ones.